# Why Do 2 PHP Redirects Cause a Redirect Loop?

Tags: php, redirect

Why do 2 PHP redirects cause a redirect loop? I'm trying to use PHP instead of page rules. Below, I'm trying to force 'https://www.' for all my web pages.

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] != "on") {
    header("Location: https://{$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}");
}
if (substr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], 0, 4) != 'www.') {
    header("Location: https://www.{$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}");
}
?>
```

Comment: `.htaccess` really would do a better job of this...

Comment: I want to keep my code flexible, so I can move from PaaS to PaaS w/o worrying about .htaccess support.

Comment: This caused an error "Too many redirects" for me. HankyPanky 's 1 liner solution is great. You need just 1 condition to check if https is off and host is non-www.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine those 2 conditions

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] != "on" || substr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], 0, 4) != 'www.') {
    header("Location: https://www.yourwebsite.com{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}");
}
```

Without that, you first redirect non https to https then you again check if https is on www so its like wasting 2 requests before getting to the real url.

Don't rely on server name if you want to keep it flexible cause it can be messed up in server configuration.

Comment: Good answer. Adding `exit;` after each `header` call should work too.

Comment: That's true, even though it will stop the loop but that will still waste 2 http requests before reaching the correct url if the user typed  `http://yourdomain.com` first

Comment: What if WWW is there, but HTTPS isn't? e.g. `http://www.google.com` -> `https://www.www.google.com`. There would be 2 www.www.?

Comment: Even then this will work fine and take you to `https://www.google.com`. Notice the condition is ***OR***, not an ***AND***. And this answer doesn't rely on server name so it wont do double `www`

Comment: whats wrong with the **And** oprator ? I dont think this will create a loop, because http://www will redirect to ssl https://www

Comment: `AND` will only make this redirect if both conditions are met. So if only 1 is met it will not redirect to the correct url. So if user types `http://www` an `AND`  will serve that request and that's not what OP desires :)